# transfers created with do_not_relay=true but not broadcasted block outputs

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I'm using the wallet RPC method `transfer` to create transactions, with `do_not_relay` set to `true`. Sometimes I have to abandon this transaction (not submitting/committing it), but the outputs get marked as spent. I run into `Known ring does not include the spent output` errors.

Is there any way to set them back to unspent, so they can be used for future transfers?

Comment: Until you (attempt) to relay, nothing is done to the outputs (they are still spendable).

Answer (score 1):

> but the outputs get marked as spent

The outputs **do not** get marked as spent until you commit (broadcast/relay/submit) the transaction.

Proof:

```
    curl -sd '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_balance"}' http://localhost:28084/json_rpc
    {
      "id": "0",
      "jsonrpc": "2.0",
      "result": {
        "balance": 9093428812095,
        "blocks_to_unlock": 0,
        "multisig_import_needed": false,
        "per_subaddress": [{
          "account_index": 0,
          "address": "9y4V...",
          "address_index": 0,
          "balance": 9093428812095,
          "blocks_to_unlock": 0,
          "label": "Primary account",
          "num_unspent_outputs": 72,
          "time_to_unlock": 0,
          "unlocked_balance": 9093428812095
        }],
        "time_to_unlock": 0,
        "unlocked_balance": 9093428812095
      }
    }
```

```
    curl -sd '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"transfer","params":{"do_not_relay":true,"destinations":[{"address":"9xBu...","amount":1000000000000}]}' http://localhost:28084/json_rpc
    {
      "id": "0",
      "jsonrpc": "2.0",
      "result": {
        "amount": 1000000000000,
        "fee": 61660000,
        "multisig_txset": "",
        "spent_key_images": {
          "key_images": ["dbc9..."]
        },
        "tx_blob": "",
        "tx_hash": "5094...",
        "tx_key": "",
        "tx_metadata": "",
        "unsigned_txset": "",
        "weight": 2202
      }
    }
```

```
    curl -sd '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_balance"}' http://localhost:28084/json_rpc
    {
      "id": "0",
      "jsonrpc": "2.0",
      "result": {
        "balance": 9093428812095,
        "blocks_to_unlock": 0,
        "multisig_import_needed": false,
        "per_subaddress": [{
          "account_index": 0,
          "address": "9y4V...",
          "address_index": 0,
          "balance": 9093428812095,
          "blocks_to_unlock": 0,
          "label": "Primary account",
          "num_unspent_outputs": 72,
          "time_to_unlock": 0,
          "unlocked_balance": 9093428812095
        }],
        "time_to_unlock": 0,
        "unlocked_balance": 9093428812095
      }
    }
```